# PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

The following method was put on the default global queue in order to get a few photos from device. if system version is greater than iOS 8, `Photos` framework is used, otherwise `ALAssetLibrary`.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
   [self getPhotos:^(NSArray *photos) {
       dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];
}

dispatch_time_t timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC));

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, timeout);


- (void)getPhotos:(MyCallBack)callback {

  Class PHPhotoLibrary_class = NSClassFromString(@"PHPhotoLibrary");

   if (PHPhotoLibrary_class) {

    PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];


    if (status != PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        return;
    }

    PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options:nil];

  }       
}
```

The app crashes, on 64bit device, such as iPhone 5S and newer model, the stack trace is like this.

```
Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: TRAP_BRKPT at 0x190c41b60
Crashed Thread:  25

Thread 25 Crashed:
0   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41b60 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionFailedWithNoVersionFromServer] :444 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
1   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
2   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
3   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
4   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
5   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
6   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
7   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
9   PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
10  PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c41ef8 +[PLModelMigrator _validateCurrentModelVersionAttempt:] :316 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
11  PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190c43688 +[PLModelMigrator createDatabase] :508 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
12  PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190b7c1cc -[PLPhotoLibrary loadDatabase:] :808 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
13  PhotoLibraryServices            0x0000000190b71f70 -[PLPhotoLibrary initWithTransientContext:name:] :560 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
14  Photos                          0x0000000191722418 ___45-[PHPhotoLibrary backgroundQueuePhotoLibrary]_block_invoke :60 (in Photos)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184bb21bc __dispatch_client_callout :16 (in libdispatch.dylib)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184bb2fb0 _dispatch_once_f :56 (in libdispatch.dylib)
17  Photos                          0x00000001917223d4 -[PHPhotoLibrary backgroundQueuePhotoLibrary] :156 (in Photos)
18  Photos                          0x0000000191722604 -[PHPhotoLibrary photoLibraryForCurrentQueueQoS] :80 (in Photos)
19  Photos                          0x0000000191722578 -[PHPhotoLibrary managedObjectContextForCurrentQueueQoS] :24 (in Photos)
20  Photos                          0x00000001917611bc -[PHQuery _createFetchRequestIncludingBasePredicate:] :140 (in Photos)
21  Photos                          0x0000000191761c5c -[PHQuery fetchRequest] :52 (in Photos)
22  Photos                          0x0000000191783988 -[PHFetchResult initWithQuery:oids:registerIfNeeded:usingManagedObjectContext:] :376 (in Photos)
23  Photos                          0x0000000191783c2c -[PHFetchResult initWithQuery:] :100 (in Photos)
24  Photos                          0x0000000191763b5c -[PHQuery executeQuery] :52 (in Photos)
25  Photos                          0x00000001916c2998 ___67+[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:subtype:options:]_block_invoke :72 (in Photos)
26  Photos                          0x000000019175fe48 +[PHObject authorizationAwareFetchResultWithOptions:fetchBlock:] :88 (in Photos)
27  Photos                          0x00000001916c2944 +[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:subtype:options:] :84 (in Photos)
```

Usually on 32bit devices, such as iPhone5, iPhone4S, crash report is like this:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1b448ad4
Crashed Thread:  1
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'  reason: 'CoreData: Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel.  nil is an illegal URL parameter'
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1bca0df7 ___exceptionPreprocess :131 (in CoreFoundation)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1af03077 _objc_exception_throw :39 (in libobjc.A.dylib)
2   CoreData                        0x1dc190c5 +[NSManagedObjectContext initialize] :1 (in CoreData)
3   PhotoLibraryServices            0x256a45d5 ___44+[PLManagedObjectContext managedObjectModel]_block_invoke :89 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
4   AssetsLibraryServices           0x24fc527d ___pl_dispatch_once_block_invoke :19 (in AssetsLibraryServices)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b346083 __dispatch_client_callout :23 (in libdispatch.dylib)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1b346c65 _dispatch_once_f :43 (in libdispatch.dylib)
7   AssetsLibraryServices           0x24fc5267 _pl_dispatch_once :77 (in AssetsLibraryServices)
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x256a456d +[PLManagedObjectContext managedObjectModel] :73 (in PhotoLibraryServices)
9   Photos                          0x26139475 +[PHQuery _relationshipForFetchType:predicate:] :257 (in Photos)
10  Photos                          0x2613a4cd -[PHQuery collectionFetchType] :85 (in Photos)
11  Photos                          0x261392b1 -[PHQuery copyWithZone:] :303 (in Photos)
12  Photos                          0x26158239 -[PHFetchResult initWithQuery:oids:registerIfNeeded:usingManagedObjectContext:] :125 (in Photos)
13  Photos                          0x26158567 -[PHFetchResult initWithQuery:] :81 (in Photos)
14  Photos                          0x2613c0cb -[PHQuery executeQuery] :53 (in Photos)
15  Photos                          0x260aaf4f ___67+[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:subtype:options:]_block_invoke :73 (in Photos)
16  Photos                          0x2613898d +[PHObject authorizationAwareFetchResultWithOptions:fetchBlock:] :63 (in Photos)
17  Photos                          0x260aaf03 +[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:subtype:options:] :97 (in Photos)
```

It seems like a coredata error, I also don't understand why `AssetsLibraryServices` and `PhotoLibraryServices` both exist in the last crash report. I tried many ways but can't reproduce the crash, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your plist include a usage description? (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW17)

Comment: @danh, yes `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` is included.

Comment: At least from the 32bit crash, it seems to be an exception. Add an exception breakpoint, and type `po $arg1` in the debug prompt.

Comment: At which point in the application lifecycle are you running this code?

Comment: @Aris, app launch, I created a `NSOperationQueue` and a `NSOperation`, and add the operation to the queue.

Comment: @LeoNatan, don't know how to do that, I can't reproduce the crash, the app is on app store, when app crashes, reports will be uploaded.

Comment: @gabbler If you have reports, in there you should find the exception reason.

Comment: @LeoNatan, it is in my post, reason: 'CoreData: Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel.  nil is an illegal URL parameter'

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this either, how often do you get the crashes? Do you have a steady flow (10 per day for example) or do you get a few then they stop, then they come back again?

Comment: @Aris,it is steady, many users are impacted, one particular user has over 200 crashes over the last 2 days, each day the total crash amount increases a little bit. The crashes are always the same as in my posts, the first one happens more than the last one.

Comment: You want to get all photos from photo library then I will help you. In those I got all photos as per creation date so you can use predicate for getting few photos

Answer (score 3):

A couple things are missing here, mainly context for your call to `getPhotos` and I notice you never do anything with `smartAlbums` or call back. Maybe you just didn't include it because you didn't think it was relevant.

Anyway, I created a new project (including core data) and here is literally everything I did. Working with no crash:

1) Added `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` to plist

2) Added the following to `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

typedef void (^MyCallBack)(NSArray *photos);
```

3) Replace the default implementation of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m` with this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {

        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
                [self getPhotos:^(NSArray *photos) {
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                }];
            });
        }
    }];

    dispatch_time_t timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC));

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, timeout);

    return YES;
}

- (void)getPhotos:(MyCallBack)callback {

    Class PHPhotoLibrary_class = NSClassFromString(@"PHPhotoLibrary");

    if (PHPhotoLibrary_class) {

        PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary options:nil];

        NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        int i = 0;
        for (PHAssetCollection *assetCollection in smartAlbums)
        {
            i++;

            PHFetchResult *smartAlbum = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollection options:nil];

            int j = 0;
            for (PHAsset *asset in smartAlbum)
            {
                j++;

                [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
                 requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                 options:nil
                 resultHandler:^void(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {

                     [photos addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
                     if (i == [smartAlbums count] && j == [smartAlbum count]) {
                         callback([NSArray arrayWithArray:photos]);
                     }
                 }];

                if (i == [smartAlbums count] && j == [smartAlbum count]) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did similar things as yours with `smartAlbums`, from the crash report, crash happened on the line `fetchAssetsInAssetCollection`, codes after that seems not being executed. so I omitted that, there were 30 threads running when it crashed.

Comment: As you've said elsewhere, this may have to do with CoreData and not asset fetching. We've established that my code works in a vacuum, which is really just the code you provided with some modification. If you remove/comment out the call to getPhotos (and the associated dispatch_semaphore_wait of course), do you still crash?

Comment: It might be that Photos Framework is built on CoreData, user captured images are saved in system database, there are multiple tasks running concurrently and I am not the only one who has access to the Photos framework, it might be that the database is acquired by another thread, and it failed to response to my request. The app is on app store and I can't reproduce the crash but some user can.

Comment: Ahh I see. Yeah your first priority should be reproducing, can't ever truly fix a bug if you don't do that first

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce this issue? This is a large bounty for an unsolvable problem!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't, when app starts, a thread pool is created, some other SDK also uses Photos framework and observes photo changes,  I think it may be caused by some race condition, or when app runs in background mode, like fetch from background, then app suddenly become active, at this time requesting photos may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, it is not necessary to `getPhotos` or `fetchAssetCollectionsWithType` in sub thread. Just have a try.